# How can I fetch price for my existing office ID using self service API

Tags: amadeus

I already have an Amadeus Office ID. I have been using it on the old version of Amadeus XML API. Now I want to use the new Self-service API and want to fetch the pricing for the Office ID I have. In the self-service API I only see rates to be fetched via a token, but how can I fetch rates using the office ID I already have?

regards,
Kavita